# Auth::user() with a relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a regular `users` table, but I also have a `user_settings` table with the following relationship in my `UserSettings.php` file:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

And a settings method within my `User.php` file:

```
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserSettings');
}
```

I want to be able to access the user and their settings by doing `Auth::user()`, but doing `Auth::user()->settings->column_name` gives me an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

How can I get the user's settings using `Auth::user()`?

Comment: Why is it `App\Models\User` and not `App\User`? Have you created a folder `Models` and kept your model files in them?

Comment: User is logged in right? First try `dump()` `Auth::user()`, `Auth::user()->settings`  and find out what is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

You can access it like so:

```
var_dump(Auth::user()->settings);
```

You cannot access it like so `Auth::user()->settings->column_name` because you have to foreach it.

```
foreach(Auth::user()->settings as $setting) {
     var_dump($setting->column_name);
}
```

Comment: Did this help you? @user6484209

Comment: Did this help you? @user6484209

Answer (score 0):

You must set up a settings method within User model:

```
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Settings');
}
```

Comment: @user6484209 Does `Auth::user()->settings()->column_name` return an error too? Can you print `Auth::user()->settings | Auth::user()->settings()`or it throws an error too?

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting

> Trying to get property of non-object

error as there may be no entry in `user_settings` table for the particular user.

Your relationships look correct.

Just go to `tinker` and `find` the user for whom you are getting the error. Then try accessing the `settings` for that user.

Comment: There definitely is an entry in `user_settings` for the user.